# Grails 3.2.6 with spring security. In memory h2 database is not created when saving users

Tags: grails, h2

I didn't find a solution from other postings although this seems a problems that others have encountered.

This is my application.yml

```
---
grails:
    profile: web-plugin
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: bioprofile
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        dialect : com.hp.opr.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:blogDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

    master:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:masterDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

but when the application starts and in the bootstrap I try to add some users:

```
    User admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'password')
    admin.save(flush: true)
    User user = new User(username: 'user', password: 'user')
    user.save(flsuh:true)

    Role adminRole = new Role(authority: Role.ROLE_ADMIN)
    adminRole.save(flush:true)

    Role userRole = new Role(authority: Role.ROLE_USER)
    userRole.save(flush:true)

    UserRole.create(admin, adminRole)
    UserRole.create(admin, userRole)
    UserRole.create(user, userRole)
```

no database is created. 
However if I open the console from the url: http://localhost:8080/dbconsole than a database is created.
Any idea why ?

Comment: any validation errors maybe?

Comment: This is not related to security

Answer (score 1):

You are using the in-memory configuration of H2 in your grails config, so no database file is created. But when you open the dbconsole, there problably is a connection string with a file instead of in-memory configuration, so a db file is created. Change the config in the dbconsole configuration.